# a funny thing happens... ExecutorCompletionService

Tags: java, executorservice, futuretask, inetaddress

I have an application written in java that needs to find all the reachable hosts on the network.

I use `InetAddress.isReachable()` to do this with a timeout of 2000 milliseconds.

I look up the current local machine's IP address and based on that I attempt to reach the other IP addresses that end 1 - 255 missing out the local machines IP address.

It all works fine single threaded, just takes a long time as most of the IP addresses are not reachable as they do not exist so use up the 2 second timeout.

To speed things up (and try out concurrency in action :: Brian Goetz) i tried using `Future` and `Callable` etc.

This all went fine as well.

However i fancied using `ExecutorCompletionService` to give my users a more responsive application, so they could see results as they came available using

```
Future<Reach> reachedFuture = completionService.take();
```

Running this on a singleprocessor machine with the following config causes only 1 of the four reachable hosts to be identified:

```
private static final int poolSize = 10;
private static final int maxPoolSize = 10;
private static final long keepAliveTime = 120;

private static final LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> queue
        = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(20);

private static final ExecutorService executorService
        = new ThreadPoolExecutor(poolSize, maxPoolSize, keepAliveTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS, queue);

private static final CompletionService<Reach> completionService
        = new ExecutorCompletionService<Reach>(executorService);
```

Changing it to this on a quad core machine also made it fail to detect all the reachable hosts:

```
private static final int poolSize
        = Math.max(2,Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());

private static final int maxPoolSize
        = Math.max(2,Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
```

By changing the `InetAddress.isReachable()` timeout to 10 seconds made the last config work ok.

Also by changing the config as follows on the quad core machine also made it work with a 2 second timeout:

```
private static final int poolSize = 2;
private static final int maxPoolSize = 2;
```

Am I missing something very obvious why this happens?

What stops `InetAddress.isReachable(2000)` from detecting all the reachable hosts on my network?

Why does attempting to run multiple `InetAddress.isReachable()` calls fail?

Comment: Have you tried to use `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` to see whether it's the threading code causing the issue?  This will at least guide us in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I wrote a little test script on my Mac and I can't get it to fail -- regardless of the size of the pool.  I did change the `LinkedBlockingQueue` to be unlimited otherwise I couldn't submit all of the jobs.  Also, after a while the `isReachable()` method was throwing a `ConnectException` so I had to handle that specifically.  Is this the problem with your code @user423199?

Here's the code:

> http://pastie.org/2460991

I'm wondering what OS you are running this on?  Certain IP stacks may not like multiple threads doing ICMP packets within the same process.  I would have thought that all modern operating systems would be smart about that but this may be a potential issue.  It also may be some bug between the Java JRE and the OS stack.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "Certain IP stacks may not like multiple threads doing ICMP packets within the same process": wouldn't that be a bug in the implementation of `InetAddress.isReachable()` for that platform? The Java API does not restrict it to one thread.

Comment: Probably or a limitation in the IP stack of the OS.  I was speculating actually.  Not sure if it would every happen but I thought I'd mention it.